# Trying to fetch emails via python

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to fetch inboxs/emails from my gmail  by using python. However, the code im using doesnt reem to run? I'm following a tutorial and my output is different.  I'm new to python.

```
import email   
import imaplib

username = '****@gmail.com'
password = '****'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login(username, password)

mail.select("inbox")
```

[When I run it via visual studio, I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ1KO.png)

I turned on let secure apps access feature on my google account, turned on imap on my gmail settings.  What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to fetch emails from gmail and view inboxes and such.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you think that your code isn't running? Also, what error?

Comment: Hi, it is not a really good thing to put real passwords online especially in a public forum.

Comment: whoops, removed the passwords. Was just a test email.  The error is hyperlinked. It just returns this in terminal: PS C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Coding\Email downloader> & C:/Users/Nathan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/Coding/Email downloader/email.py"

Comment: Please include errors as text and not as images.  That said, your image doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I believe the issue is with my visual studio terminal. Running it via cmd after calling "py" as another user suggested, it runs my code without a error.

Comment: Why do you use IMAP and not Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code is fine.
[test](https://repl.it/join/icffsgrg-danielben1)

Comment: Well, your new code does seem to retrieve emails.  

I was watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gql_NQv3ND4 and he was able to get a response back. I cant even get that in my terminal.

Comment: Try to run it through your windows' cmd. Write python3 on the cmd ( try python if it didn't work)  and then enter your code. I recommend using Pycharm for python code.

Comment: typing out py in cmd and then running the code gives me the desired execution. So I assume this kind of code cant be run within python and see the output?

Comment: No, I'm assuming you are not running python correctly on your visual studio. try to fix it or install Pycharm. Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZUNUB6nz3g&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge2

Comment: This answer should be a comment instead. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Jescanellas He doesn't have the required points to comment. It is really annoying to see people downvote or post the comment you did and don't take into account the answerers points

Comment: I know he doesn't. This answer is still low quality. We all had less than 50 points at some point, but this limitation has a good reason behind it. I find more annoying seeing 4 word answers that didn't take any effort. My comment was constructive, so you can ask an admin what do they think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I added a print statement and trying to access the content.

```
import imaplib

username = '****@gmail.com'
password = '****'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP)
mail.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)    

for i in mail.list()[1]:
  l = i.decode().split(' "/" ')
  print(l[0] + " = " + l[1]) #should print the mail content that you can use as needed
```

Comment: this code is great too, managed to get the output displayed in visual studio terminal.